# No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: selection in json user skin?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to set the style of my UI with JSON.

In this tutorial: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx
The uiskin.json doesn't work for me. I removed all the other styles that i don't need and this is my actual skin code:

uiskin.json:

```
{
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
        default-font: {
            file: AlanDen50.fnt
        }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
        green: {
            a: 1,
            b: 0,
            g: 1,
            r: 0
        },
        blue: {
            a: 1,
            b: 1,
            g: 0,
            r: 0
        },
        white: {
            a: 1,
            b: 1,
            g: 1,
            r: 1
        },
        red: {
            a: 1,
            b: 0,
            g: 0,
            r: 1
        },
        black: {
            a: 1,
            b: 0,
            g: 0,
            r: 0
        }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
        default: {
            font: default-font,
            fontColor: blue,
            downFontColor: red
        }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
        default: {
            font: default-font,
            fontColor: blue
        }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
        default: {
            selection: selection,
            font: default-font,
            fontColor: blue,
            cursor: cursor
        }
    }
}
```

and this is PlayScreen.java:

```
    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

    TextField inpName = new TextField("Nome", skin);
    inpName.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 40);
```

The errors I get is:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:73)
    at com.me.dunbar.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java:43)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at com.me.dunbar.DunBarGame.switchScreen(DunBarGame.java:32)
    at com.me.dunbar.DunBarGame.create(DunBarGame.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:658)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:94)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
selection (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:758)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:861)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:411)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:805)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:432)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:421)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:417)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:835)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:411)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:656)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: selection
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:284)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:132)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:410)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:751)
    ... 17 more
```

Now, if I delete 'selection' and 'cursor' from json the app runs but I don't see any text field!

I'm using the gdx nightly build (22 dec 2013) but this wasn't working even in 0.9.9 stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you haven't registered a texture named `selection`. `TextFieldStyle` requires the `selection` field to hold the texture that should be drawn when the user selects some text.

To register such texture(s) just do so:

```
skin.addRegions(someAtlasTexture)
```

Obviously, the atlas should contain such region(s). Also, you should define `background` field of `TextFieldStyle` (usually, 9-patch region) to see text field corners.

Comment: Ok, but when you do this: Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json")), that's where the crash occurs. There doesn't seem to be a way to add a texture ABCXYZ (whatever it is).